# DNN New User Verification Code Not Working

Tags: dotnetnuke, registration, verification, user-registration, dotnetnuke-8

I've got a site setup where the user registration is set to 'Verified' but the link, that is emailed the new user to verify the account, is broken. The page says: "DNN Error No sites currently exist for this installation. - 503 Service Unavailable"

The link would look something like this:
[MYSITE]/default.aspx?ctl=Login&username=[USERNAME]&verificationcode=[CODE]

The site then rewrites it to:
[MYSITE]/login/username/[USERNAME]?verificationcode=[CODE]

After initial registration BUT before the user is verified, DNN automatically logs the user in (though limited access because they are unverified) but if user logs out THEN follows link from email, then verification works fine

Using DNN Version 08.00.04 (226)

Comment: Are you using the Ifinity URL rewriter tools?

Comment: @ChrisHammond No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/pull/1719/commits/cf956a062319e69ae5949efac4f8c5d4b475b0e7

Change 2 line in this file: /DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/DNN/Login.ascx

Change line 46 from:

```
var actionLinks = $("a#dnn_ctr<%=ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin");
```

To:

```
var actionLinks = $("a#dnn_ctr<%#ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin");
```

AND line 60 from:

```
var $loginButton = $('#dnn_ctr<%=ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin');
```

To:

```
var $loginButton = $('#dnn_ctr<%#ModuleId > Null.NullInteger ? ModuleId.ToString() : ""%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin');
```